# How do I get apache httpd server to map the name of accented html elements to unaccented files

Tags: mod-rewrite, character-encoding, apache

The server does not support characters in Portuguese and I have images that contain Latin characters as intrusão.png, localização.png, inundações.png, etc ... However I need to keep the source of the page with the names of files in Portuguese. What i need is when the page is loading, while it is requesting the file from server, the server replace the characters ç for c, â for a, õ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well your problem:

- you have real files on the server which does not contain accented characters, only ASCII7 things
- you want to keep references to theses files with the accented names, so you will have url containing urlencoded references to theses files

So the Webserver receive a request for `images/localização.png` (which is in fact urlencoded by browsers in: `images/localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o.png`) and should return the file `/path/to/documentroot/images/localizacao.png`. A **transliteration** problem.

I'm quite sure you cannot do that with simple rewriteRules. But if you have a real access to apache configuration (not just the .htaccess ugly and limited files, I mean the real configuration files, else you cannot do anything), then you could try something with **RewriteMap**.

[Rewritemap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) is already a quite advanced usage of mod-rewrite, and we'll use the more complex Rewritemap keyword, which is `prg:`, allowing a call to an external mapper program written in the language you prefer.

First you record an external program (in the Virtualhost configuration scope, not in a `Directory`).

```
RewriteLock /var/lock/transliterate_rewritemaplock.lock
RewriteMap transliteration prg:/path/to/modrewritemap_transliterate.pl
```

Then you use it in a rewriteRule, maybe with some RewriteCond before.

```
<Directory /my/images/>
    RewriteRule - ${transliteration:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L]
</Directory>
```

And last but not least you write this external program ( here `/path/to/modrewritemap_transliterate.pl`, a perl script). I've tried to write one with [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Text-Unidecode-0.04/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm). But this CPAN perl module will maybe have to be installed on the server.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$| = 1; # Turn off I/O buffering
use utf8;
use Text::Unidecode;
while (<>) {
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ m/(.*?)\.png/){
        print unidecode($1).".png\n";    
    } else {
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

On the command line, this converts `images/localização.png` to `images/localizaASSAPSo.png`, which is not really good. But I'm not sure my command line is sending real utf8. On your webserver you'll have to check as well if you receive real utf8 or something else (I think you shouldn't get the urlencoded version). And you'll have to find a language able to transliterate your input...

Transliteration is a complex problem. Are you sure you **MUST** keep the accented letters in images url? Maybe the solution will be less complex on this side, and who really cares about image names?

Comment: Yes, i must keep accented letters in image url. And thank you for your answer. I'll try and say something. It seems really complex.

Comment: Do you have root access to the Apache configuration or do you only have access through `.htaccess` files?  The answer to this Q fundamentally impacts possible solutions.

Comment: i have access to the apache configuration in my computer for test but on server that i'm hosting the web site i've not.

Comment: Without this access you wont be able to use RewriteMap. So I don't think you have a solution (I was thinking about iconv as well). Maybe with a PHP based bootstrapper for your images...

Comment: i solved it with javascript. i know isnt a great thing but solved.

Comment: yes, not really nice, all indexation bots will see your images in 404, bad thing. try to put the real name in href attribute, the localized one in rel attribute, then in js move the rel value in href (ugly as well :-) )